# change font on my web page

Tags: html, css

Hi :) I have problems using webfonts in my web page: the stylesheet and the html file are in different folders. In this way all the css code works except the font one; if I move the stylesheet to the folder of the html page the font changes.
Can someone explain me why this is happening?

HTML code in the not working case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>example1</h1>
        <p>example2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML code in the working case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>example1</h1>
        <p>example2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code (it's the same in each case):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  src: url('other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot');
  src: url('other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.woff') format('woff'),
       url('other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.svg#Raleway-ExtraLight') format('svg'),
       url('other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: Raleway;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

URLs in CSS are relative to the URL of the *CSS* file, not the HTML document.

When you move the CSS file, you change the directory that `other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot` et al are calculated from.

e.g. you are saying `/other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot` instead of /css/other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot`

Possibly you want to explicitly put `/` at the front of the URL.

Comment: Thanks man! When I wrote the code I was a little absent-minded and I didn't notice that stupid error :/

Answer (score 0):

The font URLs in the CSS file are relative to the location of the CSS file, not the HTML page. Your current URL, `'other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot'` is the same as `'[Your CSS folder]/other/font/Raleway-ExtraLight.eot'`.

If your CSS and fonts are in different folders, in this structure:

```
-css
   -styles.css
-fonts
    -Raleway.eot
```

then the url to the font should be `'../fonts/Raleway.eot'` (`..` moves up a level).